# Get Fontawesome-icon into the same line as a w3-input field

Tags: html, css, row, font-awesome, w3.css

So I was working on a webpage as I ran into this problem over here. I wanted to create my first form with w3.css (not bootstrap), which worked perfectly fine. But after trying multiple times to add a `fa`-Fontawesome-Icon in front of my text input field (the height of the fa-icon matches the height of the text input, they are both in the same row), I´m now asking you guys in the community out there -
How can I get the Fontawesome-Icon to the same height and same row/line of a text input field?
Here´s my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="w3-container w3-white">
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m12">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><p><input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" style="width: 50%;"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I get this working?
Thanks for all answers in advance, as always,
 - SearchingSolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.input-icon{
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="w3-container w3-white">
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m12">
      
<p>
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x fa-fw input-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" style="width: 50%;">
</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This does the trick. There are better ways but this is the base. You can remove or adapt the expand effect. You can also use position absolute on the icon and padding on the container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `input` element inherits `display: block` `.w3-input` class. You can overwrite this by simply giving an id to the element and setting `display: inline`. Add those:

```
#inline-input {
    display: inline;
}
```

*

```
<input id = "inline-input" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" style="width: 50%;">
```

Edit: Also remove `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: This worked too, but I felt more comfortable with the marked solution. Thanks anyways :)